# Is it good practice to return pointer from function in c?

Tags: c, function, pointers

For Ex:

```
int *point() {
 int *q = malloc(sizeof(int));
 *q=20;
 return q;
}

int main() {
    int *a = point();
    free(a);
}
```

I wonder if this is a good practice in c?

Comment: Based on the current answers this clearly a subjective question.  There appears to be no objective criteria for determining goodness or badness of this coding practice, and there are arguments both for and against it.

Comment: @Mark: that's nonsense. Of course there are arguments for and against returning a pointer, but that's because it's *sometimes* a sensible thing to do, and sometimes not. A good answer, since you seem to be in doubt, would be on that explains *when* it is a good practice to return a pointer, and *why* it is/is not.

Comment: And the next time you decide to vote for a question to be closed, I suggest you read the close reason before you click on it. The close reason does not say "subjective". It says "subjective and argumentative".  It is the "argumentative" part that's really important. No one wants a flame war, after all. But this question, like many other subjective questions, can be objectively answered. @DGM's answer, for example, is objective. It makes an observation about how commonly this is done, it explains how returning pointers should be done, and it explains what the problem with the OP's example is.

Comment: I agree with jalf.  This question does not fulfill the criteria for closing.  In fact some of the answers contain some useful information for C beginners.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Returning pointers is quite common.  The problem, or discipline needed, is to be sure where the responsibility of freeing memory lies.  This example smells because it's not clear that it needed to be free'd in main().

Comment: Correction: It's clear from the whole code sample, but if an API user didn't have access to the code for `point()` it would be unclear. When a function returns a pointer, document if it needs to be `free()`-d (or if other, more specialized cleanup needs to be used).

Comment: Yes, it's easy when the function is right there in front of you. It's not so easy when it's buried in a 10,000 line library. :)

Answer (score 8):

I think the problem is the free(a); I think you should add a release_point() function.

Comment: Disagree. If more cleanup than `free()` is required, then yes, add a destructor function. But if your cleanup function is nothing more than `void release(mytype *p) { free(p); }` then your cleanup function is kind of unnecessary. You can document that anyone using your datatype needs to call `free()` just as easily as you can document that they should call your custom release/destructor function. Plus, everyone knows what `free()` does.

Comment: @Chris: Having a release_point() function would insure that, if any cleanup should be required in the future, refactoring of the entire application is not required.

Comment: agree, but point should be called something like create_point(). That way it makes me immediately think I should destroy the point later.

Comment: @Chris: I agree with you that free() is all that *should* be needed. But Windows and its multiple memory heaps (release, debug and who knows what) means that a DLL had better define cleanup functions for all its alloc functions.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the C example on the [wikipedia page for opaque pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer). It's a way of structuring code where you manage the memory fully on one side of the interface.

Answer (score 3):

The only real danger I know of with returning a pointer to allocated memory is this: If your library is compiled on Windows and linked to one instance of the Visual C++ runtime library (MSVCRT), for example, it is statically linked to it, and a client program is linked to another instance, for example, it is linked to the DLL, then they each have a different malloc arena, and pointers returned by the library cannot be freed by the program. Any attempt to do so is likely to cause the program to crash.

Answer (score 3):

I would advocate always having your own function to free memory that is returned by your library, unless you are returning something trivial such as a string.

The reason for this is that, if you change the structure of what you are returning such that a simple `free` will no longer be enough (because you add to the returned object pointers to allocated memory that themselves need to be freed), clients will not need to change their code; you can just change your existing free function.

So having your own free function insulates clients from the structure of objects returned by your library, leaving you free to change the structure of your objects without affecting clients.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a consistent system of knowing which functions return pointers that must be freed (such as using the word `create` or `new` in the function's name) then it makes it easier to manage your memory.

```
int *createPoint()
{
    int *q = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (*q)
       *q = 20;
    return q;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's often good practice, but your example is one of the few cases where it's very bad practice. You should never use dynamic allocation and pointers for individual objects which are small and do not contain (and will never need to contain) pointers themselves. Obtaining a 4-byte `int` with `malloc` uses at least 16 bytes once you factor in bookkeeping overhead, but perhaps much more importantly, it means you have to worry about possible allocation failures (and how to handle them) and managing when to free the object.

Some examples of objects you shouldn't be allocating like this:

- any basic type
- ordered pairs/coordinates/vectors/matrices/etc. (as long as they're fixed-dimension)
- ip addresses
- color values

Of course the one time it might make sense to allocate and return a pointer to such objects is when you're allocating an *array* of them.